# Index OutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I am trying to put an integer inside the array by subtracting the initialized value in every loop. This code seems right for me, but the compiler always claims that "Index was outside the bounds of the array.". Am I doing something wrong here particularly in itr part?

```
  static void Main()
  {
      int itr = 0;
      int[] arr = {};

      for(int i = 2305; i > 0; i-=576)
      {
            arr[itr] = i;
            itr+=1;
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
  }
```

Comment: What do you think is the size/length of your array `arr`? (Hint: check the value of `arr.Length`)

Comment: array size is 4, but inside the loop it's 5? I tried to subtract the index by 1 in every loop but still it doesn't work

Comment: *"array size is 4"* how do you know that? (Hint: according to the code in your question, it is not...)

Answer (score 2):

This line creates an empty array (so the `Length` is **0**):

```
int[] arr = {};
```

You should specify a size for your array.In your case the size could be:

```
int[] arr = new int[2305 / 576 + 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your int array 'arr' is of length 0;
Because you aren't setting a size, or values for it, the array has no value at all.

this is an iteration that will work;

```
int[] arr = new int[ 1000 ];
int itr = 2305;

for ( int i = arr.Length-1; i > -1; i-- ) {
    itr -= 576;
    arr[ i ] = itr;
}
```